# FB.ui feed stopped showing iframe and popups instead

Tags: javascript, android, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-iframe

I'm using the following code to share content from my site:

```
  FB.ui({
      display: 'popup',
      method: 'feed',
      link: burl
  }, function(response){
      if (response && !response.error_code) {   
           //log stats
      } else {
           console.log('not shared'); 
      }});
```

Until a couple of days ago, if shared from a mobile device the share dialog was shown in an iframe and in a popup for desktop. Now, suddenly, if shared from mobile I get a popup window with display set to "touch" instead of an iframe.

The problem with this:

When a user shares the content from the popup window, the callback function doesn't fires at all from a mobile device(works from chrome mobile emulator thou).

If using the chrome mobile emulator I get:

1. When I close the "share dialog popup" the response function fires and I got "not shared" in the console.
2. When I click "cancel" on the share dialog I got this error in the console:

   ```
   Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL   'https://m.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/feed' from frame with URL 'http://example.com/article'. The frame attempting navigation is neither same-origin with the target, nor is it the target's parent or opener.
   ```

From this error it looks like the problem is related to iframe cross domain security but I'm using the standard facebook JDK and made no changes to  the site.

I've tried to setting the "display" parameter to "iframe", "page" or with no "display" parameter at all with no change.
Please point me to the right direction.

Thanks,
Vadim

Comment: better use "share" instead of "feed", if you only add the url as parameter anyway. in general, facebook made it harder to check if something was shared though, because people often abuse it for share gating - which is not allowed.

Comment: The thing is, it worked a few days ago without any problem....The "share" dialog doesn't provide callback function(not that works anyway)

Comment: i would not be surprised if facebook would turn off the response for the feed dialog too. after all, the feed dialog was deprecated for a while and facebook suggested using the share dialog...as i commented, it was often abused for share gating. the app developer should not know if someone shared something, because it´s totally up to the user. bad for logging purposes though, i guess that´s what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually, they brought it back to life.

Comment: Actually, they brought it back to life. I noticed two things: 1. It works on IOS. Only Android facebook app doesn't return a callback. 2. From the docs, "iframe is shown only if user is logged in to facebook". Its the embedded browser in the mobile app so the user must be logged in but no iframe. I remember that when it worked, I could FB.me in the console and get me user name. Now, when doing "FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){console.log(response)})" I get "not_authorized" in the console. The facebook app is not mine and I never "approved" or "logged" to it before.

Comment: i know they brought it back, that´s why i said "it was deprecated for a while" ;)

Comment: if the app is not yours, why do you want to get the share status? not sure if i understand...

Comment: I mean that my partner is the one that registered the app from his fb account. We didn't implemented any login dialogs to the app so I couldn't been "connected" to the app in the first place. I figured that when a feed dialog gets invoked, an access token is generated with generic permissions. I've even checked it with the debugger back then. Tested with multiple devices... Could be that facebook changed the behavior? I cant find anything in the docs..

Comment: well, the dialogs should always work without authorization, i don´t think they have changed this.

Comment: The real problem is not the disappearance of the iframe. The real issue is when shared from the facebook app from an android phone, I get no response back. The function fires but the response is empty, both for shared and canceled.